# Display all given IDs when using IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a CTE that displays each record per user id to *horizontally* (instead of the usual "listed" way) based on given user id's and a specific date range. I'm struggling finding a way to display every record given because sometimes in that period that user isn't registered but I still need to know if he registered or not. I could check manually but sometimes I get over 200+ id's.

This it's what I get with my current code

```
id reg1 reg2 reg3
-----------------
x  a    b    c
```

This it's what I expect

```
id reg1 reg2 reg3
-----------------
x  a    b    c
y  NULL NULL NULL -- 'y' doesn't exists, ergo, it should display the id and nulls on the rest of columns.
```

My code

```
;WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT PER_PRO, ID_HR, NOM_INC, rut_dv, dias_durAC, INI, FIN,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID_HR ORDER BY ULT_ACT) AS RN
   FROM dbo.inf_lic WHERE PER_PRO = --GIVEN DATE PERIOD
)
SELECT ID_HR,rut_dv,NOM_INC,
       max(case when rn = 1 then DIAS_DURAC end) as DIAS_DUR1,
       max(case when rn = 1 then INI end) as INI1,
       max(case when rn = 1 then FIN end) as FIN1,

       max(case when rn = 2 then DIAS_DURAC end) as DIAS_DUR2,
       max(case when rn = 2 then INI end) as INI2,
       max(case when rn = 2 then FIN end) as FIN2,

       max(case when rn = 3 then DIAS_DURAC end) as DIAS_DUR3,
       max(case when rn = 3 then INI end) as INI3,
       max(case when rn = 3 then FIN end) as FIN3,

       max(case when rn = 4 then DIAS_DURAC end) as DIAS_DUR4,
       max(case when rn = 4 then INI end) as INI4,
       max(case when rn = 4 then FIN end) as FIN4
FROM CTE
WHERE RUT_DV in (/*GIVEN VALUES*/) 
GROUP BY ID_HR,RUT_DV, NOM_INC;
```

Comment: Why do you need to use an IN clause at all?  Your question is unclear because your sample data and results don't match the column names in your code.

Comment: Yes, I need data from those id's specifically whether they exists or not @TabAlleman

Comment: put the whole list of the possible Ids you have in a view (it should be something like select distinct(id) from table) ,  then make a left outer join of your current query with that view

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an "in period" flag, which can be combined with `RN`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
      SELECT l.*,
             (CASE WHEN PER_PRO = ?
                   THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_HR ORDER BY ULT_ACT)
              END) as rn
      FROM dbo.inf_lic l
     )
SELECT ID_HR,rut_dv,NOM_INC,
       max(case when rn = 1 then DIAS_DURAC end) as DIAS_DUR1,
       max(case when rn = 1 then INI end) as INI1,
       max(case when rn = 1 then FIN end) as FIN1,

       max(case when rn = 2 then DIAS_DURAC end) as DIAS_DUR2,
       max(case when rn = 2 then INI end) as INI2,
       max(case when rn = 2 then FIN end) as FIN2,

       max(case when rn = 3 then DIAS_DURAC end) as DIAS_DUR3,
       max(case when rn = 3 then INI end) as INI3,
       max(case when rn = 3 then FIN end) as FIN3,

       max(case when rn = 4 then DIAS_DURAC end) as DIAS_DUR4,
       max(case when rn = 4 then INI end) as INI4,
       max(case when rn = 4 then FIN end) as FIN4
FROM CTE
WHERE RUT_DV in (/* GIVEN VALUES */) 
GROUP BY ID_HR, RUT_DV, NOM_INC;
```